# Rolling dice a specific number of times Java

Tags: java, netbeans, dice

I am new to Java and this is what I have to do:

If a player gets double sixes on 2 dice 5 times in 1 round, a random number between 10 and 30 is picked. For example, if that number is 20 the other two dice should be rolled twenty times and you multiply the two numbers and get the cumulative product.

This is just a small part of the big program and this is what I have done so far:

```
if (ninedice == 6 && sixdice == 6) {
    rolledDoubleSix++;
    if (rolledDoubleSix == 5) {
        dicerolls = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * (30 - 10 + 1) + 10);
        int ninediceproduct = dicerolls;
        int sixdiceproduct = dicerolls;
        if (ninediceproduct > 0) {
            ninediceproduct=(int)Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9);
        }
        if (sixdiceproduct > 0) {
            sixdiceproduct = dicerolls * (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);
        }
        int cumulativetotal = 0;
        int cumulative = sixdiceproduct * ninediceproduct;
        cumulativetotal = cumulativetotal + cumulative;
        accountpoints = accountpoints + cumulativetotal;
        accountptsoutput.setText("" + accountpoints);
```

The problem I have is that I do not know how to make the two dice roll a specific number of times. If the random number between 10 and 30 is 18, how do I make those dices roll 18 times?

Comment: Have you learnt about "for loops" yet?

Comment: Not a lot. But how can that help?

Comment: Well, a "for loop" lets you repeat something over and over.  It seems like you might want one here.  So I would recommend reading about them in the online Java tutorial that Oracle provides.

Answer (score 0):

Like other people have said use the for loop.

Another way is just to have multiple variables. Also use java.util.Random (and subsequently the r.nextInt(seed) + 1 method) not  Math.random.

Here is how I would do it

```
Random r = new Random();
int firstSpin = r.nextInt(6) + 1; //+1 so result cannot be zero
int secondSpin = r.nextInt(6) + 1;
//more spins if needed
if(firstSpin == 6 && secondSpin == 6) {
//do something
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well I think what you are looking for is called a loop.

here is a basic example:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Its used to repeat code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I tried using this:                                                                                                 for(int roll=0; roll>=dicerolls; roll++) where dicerolls is random num between 10 and 30

Comment: @JohnSmith this wont execute at all, since roll is never greater or equal to diceroll (which is 15-30).  You should use "roll<=dicerolls" instead.

Comment: @JohnSmith `roll < dicerolls`, with `>=` the loop isn't entered because the initial condition is false.